# Does Spring Data REST support adding custom behavior to single repositories with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

Does Spring Data REST support adding custom behavior to single repositories with Spring Data MongoDB and exposing it as a rest resource?

For example, here is the pojo:

```
@Document
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Poet {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    private String content;
}
```

And Here is the repository:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PoetRepository extends MongoRepository<Poet, String>, MyPoetRepository {
}
```

Can I find all the distinct `title` attribute in the document `poet` by extending a custom interface? By the way, how to implement the custom interface?

Comment: You dont have to extend current interface. Try adding method `List<String> findDistinctByTitle()`

Comment: Well, it just brings me the following exception, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`, which is caused by missing argument `title` that you just declare at the method `List<String> findDistinctByTitle()`.
What's more, even though I add the argument make it `List<String> findDistinctByTitle(@Param("title") String title);`, it still doesn't work with an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must not be null!`

Comment: Are you able to access other methods like `save` and  `find` method ?

Comment: Yes, I can do it.

Comment: I have similar problem but i want to add custom behavior on save/delete method. How can i achieve this?